# SCP command for copying .txt files from one remote server to another remote server for last 10 days

Tags: ssh, scp

I have two remote hosts.
host1-> 10.2.3.2
host2-> 10.3.0.2

I have 500 txt file in one remote server. I want to copy it to another remote server using SCP command for last 10 days. I have userID & access to both server.How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Yes you can copy the files directly from server1 to server2 without passing the local client. But you will still need to compose a list of files to copy from server1 by looking at their dates (which can be done by a shell script or e.g. python script).

Comment: How can I do it in shell script to copy by dates ?